# .NET 4.5 Upgrade Results in Empty CorrelationManager.ActivityId

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, logging, trace

We have been using CorrelationManager.ActivityId for a long time to help correlate log entries across multiple threads.  We create the ActivityId on SessionStart and store it in session for use on all subsequent requests.

```
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Session["ActivityId"] == null)
        {
            var activityId = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.Session["ActivityId"] = activityId;
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = activityId;
        }
    }
```

We then reuse it from session like so:

```
    protected void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState)
        {
            if (this.Session["ActivityId"] != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = (Guid)this.Session["ActivityId"];
            }
            else
            {
                var activityId = Guid.NewGuid();
                this.Session["ActivityId"] = activityId;
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = activityId;
            }
        }
    }
```

The above has worked flawlessly for a long time.

But once we upgraded our web server to .NET 4.5.2, we randomly have empty Guids (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) logged for ActivityId. We verified this by downgrading to .NET 2.0, then installing 4.0 (not 4.5.2) and the issue disappears. Then after reinstalling .NET 4.5.2, the problem arises again.  We ran through that exercise multiple times to make sure.

I couldn't find any mention of a similar issue anywhere. We're in the process of contacting Microsoft support.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? We've got a similar kind of issue. We're setting it in OWin, but its never set in WebAPI.